# Russian data sovereignty compliance

Tags: data-storage

So there's new law requiring a copy of personal data of Russian citizens in effect since September 2015. I can't read Russian, and Western press in languages I can read is a little vague on the actual details. Can anyone hence tell me if an encrypted periodic database extraction of just the Russian people's data, stored somewhere on a Russian server, is compliant? (I.e. there's no need to actually host the app there, just store an extraction of the relevant personal data?)